# How to insert result of Stored Procedure into Temp Table without declaring Temp Table Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert the values of stored procedure into a temp table without predefining the columns for the temp table.

```
Insert Into #Temp1 Exec dbo.sp_GetAllData @Name = 'Jason'.
```

How can I do this ?  I saw an option as below but can I do it without mentioning the server name ?

```
SELECT * INTO #TestTableT FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
'EXEC tempdb.dbo.GetDBNames')
-- Select Table
SELECT *
FROM #TestTableT;
```

Comment: We are using multiple stored procedures and the number of columns output may change. Writing a server name might not be a good way from maintenance stand point

Comment: Sounds like there are some design issues here. You are creating the one proc to rule them all. This is like making a single method in a dotnet class that can do everything.

Comment: Then why don't you just use a Table-Valued function instead of an Stored Procedure. You will be able to directly select the result.

Comment: You can create a temporary table with one fake column and alter this table  in a stored procedure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table)

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a possible solution without defining temp table schema and writing server name. So, I changed the code and the queries to handle with only known schema. Code example is as below

```
    CREATE TABLE #TestTable ([name] NVARCHAR(256), [database_ID] INT);
    INSERT INTO #TestTable
    EXEC GetDBNames

    SELECT * FROM #TestTable;
```

As provided in the link https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/05/27/sql-server-how-to-insert-data-from-stored-procedure-to-table-2-different-methods/

Answer (score 2):

No-one said it had to be pretty:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p AS
SELECT 1 as x, 2 as y, 3 as z
GO
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(OBJECT_ID('p'), 0);
DECLARE @name sysname, @type sysname;

CREATE TABLE #t(fake int)

OPEN c
FETCH NEXT from c into @name, @type
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

 EXEC ('ALTER TABLE #t ADD ' + @name + ' ' + @type)
 FETCH NEXT from c into @name, @type
END

CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE c
ALTER TABLE #t DROP COLUMN fake;

INSERT INTO #t EXEC p;
GO
```

Comment: What on earth is this.

Comment: I was not able to use RECONFIGURE nor the OPENROWSET method. As bizarre as this looks, it works.

Comment: If you`select * from #t` at the end of your script, nothing is returned. SSMS just returns `Commands completed successfully.`